# Implement OAuth2.0 for OKTA with J2EE(Servlets) application

Tags: java, servlets, oauth-2.0, okta

I want to implement OAuth2.0 for my application(developed in J2EE) with OKTA. I didn't find any implementation for Oauth2.0 with J2ee and Okta . Could you please help me with finding the libraries and example code to implement Oauth2.0 for My App.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/22/servlet-authentication

Comment: Hi Matt, the shared post contains the how to do authentication from servlets , Not the OAuth2.0 implementation.

Comment: Try this one. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api

Comment: Which version of EE ? With the newest version you can use the Java Security API - which makes these things very, very simple with finished implementations available - allowing you to use OAuth with a single annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Okta's java sdk supports OAuth2.0 for Okta API's: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java